# Optional argument first in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For the user's ease, I have a function that receives an optional argument first, before the required argument. For example:

```
ns.myFunction('optional arg', function(){
    //the required callback
});
```

I'm doing this rather than doing the following since the callback body could be long, and the user might forget to override the defaults to the optional arguments:

```
ns.myFunction(function(){
    //the required callback
}, 'optional arg');
```

Currently I'm doing this to check:

```
function myFunction(first, second) {

    //if second is undefined and first is a function
    if (typeof second === 'undefined' && typeof first === 'function') { 
        second = first;
    }
}
```

Questions

- Is this the right way?
- How would I do it so that it scales, especially if there were N optional arguments that are before the required argument?

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the optional arguments at the *end* of the argument list? That's more useful in JavaScript due to the semantics of `.bind()`. The more "stable" arguments should come first, with the ones more likely to vary or be absent at the end.

Comment: @Pointy I'm just curious as to how libraries do it like this and if there was a proper method. For example, jQuery's `extend` has a deepcopy flag which is optional situated at the very first argument list.

Comment: How about using `arguments[..]`? Wouldn't iterating through the array, and stopping at the first `typeof arguments[i] === 'function'` help?

Comment: @Thrustmaster the optional arguments could also be the same type as the required argument.

Comment: _"For the user's ease"_ - IMO this would make the function far more confusing, and it wouldn't mesh well with IDEs

Comment: @Stecman for a long and deeply indented callback (like a hundred lines or more), it would be a convenience to see that optional at the very first rather than the very end.

Comment: Well I think that is in fact what jQuery does. The `.extend` function is kind-of a special case in that it has two kinds of optional arguments; one could argue that it'd be better for it to be two separate functions, but arguments like that are silly :-)

Comment: Don't write 100 line callbacks!

Answer (score 4):

This is not the *right* way because optional parameters are by convention always placed at the end. And you see a reason why: it is much easier to handle them. If the length of anonymous function is your concern, clients of your API should use function references or variables:

```
function callback1() { //...

var callback2 = function() {//...

myFunction(callbackX, optional);
```

The problem with escaping `this` can be solved with `bind()`.

If you really want to go the path of multiple optional parameters and callback at the end, I can think of two ways: `arguments` object or wrapping all optional arguments in one `options` objects.

With `arguments` you can write:

```
var lastOptionalIndex = arguments.length - 2;
var callback = arguments[lastOptionalIndex + 1];  //required callback is always last
var optionalFirst = lastOptionalIndex >=0? arguments[0] : undefined;
var optionalSecond = lastOptionalIndex >=1? arguments[1] : undefined;
//...
```

See how ugly it is compared to:

```
function myFunction(callback, firstOptional, secondOptional //...
```

With `options` wrapper object you always have two arguments:

```
function myFunction(options, callback);
```

Where `options` is just an object:

```
{
  firstOptional: 1,
  secondOptional: 'foo'
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, using an options object parameter either before or after the callback function is a good way to go. And it makes it much easier to assign default values using the extend method.

Answer (score 2):

It can easilly be done with [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs):

```
function myFunction (){
  arguments = __({first: [String], second: Function})

  // and now on, you can access your arguments by
  //   arguments.first and arguments.second
}
```

---

A very similar example can be found at [ArgueJS' first example](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs#example). Note that only the parameter in the middle is required:

```
function range(){ 
  arguments = __({start: [Number, 0], stop: Number, step: [Number, 1]})

  for(var i = arguments.start; i < arguments.stop; i += arguments.step)
    console.log(i);
}
```

repl:

```
>>> range(3)
 0
 1
 2
>>> range(3, 5)
 3
 4
>>> range(0, 5, 2)
 0
 2
 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configurate function arguments, depending on their number:

```
myFunction() {
    let first, second;
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        [first, second] = arguments;
    } else if (arguments.length === 1) {
        [second] = arguments;
    }
    if ( ! first) {
        // first is undefined, so only second argument was passed.
    }
}
```

ES6 destructuring makes code clean and suitable for scaling.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to name any of the parameters. you can simply say:

```
if (arguments.length < 2)  // There are no optional parameters
```

And retrieve each parameter via arguments[i]. The function is found at arguments[arguments.length - 1].

On a minor note, the typeof operator always returns a string, so == can be used instead of ===

Answer (score 1):

ArgueJS:

```
function range(){ 
  arguments = __({start: [Number, 0], stop: Number, step: [Number, 1]});
  for(var i = arguments.start; i < arguments.stop; i += arguments.step)
    console.log(i);
}
```

Become even prettier with ES6:

```
function range(){ 
  {start, stop, step} = __({start: [Number, 0], stop: Number, step: [Number, 1]})
  for(var i = start; i < stop; i += step)
    console.log(i);
}
```

Or CoffeeScript:

```
range = ->
  {start, stop, step} = __ {start: [Number, 0], stop: Number, step: [Number, 1]}
  console.log i for i in [start...stop] by step
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pass multiple optional parameters first, you could do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("optional:");
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length-1) alert(arguments[i]);
    alert("function: "+ arguments[arguments.length-1]);
}
```

But It's rather ugly. I think you should just put the optional stuff at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(num = 1) {
  console.log(typeof num)
}

test()           // 'number' (num is set to 1)
test(undefined)  // 'number' (num is set to 1 too)

// test with other falsy values:
test('')         // 'string' (num is set to '')
test(null)       // 'object' (num is set to null)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Answer (score -1):

A simple functional approach:

Idea:

1. Write a function myFunction(required, optional) where the optional argument is last, and thus easy
   to deal with.
2. Use function appendFirstArgumentIf() to create a new function myNewFunction(optional, required) out of myFunction.
3. Function appendFirstArgumentIf calls myFunction with the first argument moved to the last position if it passes a testfunction, otherwise it doesn't change the arguments.

_

```
 /**
 * @param {function} fn(a,...b)
 * @param {function} argumentTest - a function to test the first parameter
 * @return {function} returns a function that passes its first argument into 
  argumentTest. If argumentTest returns true, fn is called with the first 
  argument shifted to the last position else fn is called with the arguments 
   order unchanged
 */
function appendFirstArgumentIf (fn,argumentTest){
   return function(a,...b){
       return argumentTest(a) ? fn(...b,a) : fn(a,...b) 
   }
}
```

usage:

```
function myFunction(callback, string){
    string = string ? string : 'Default Message'
    callback(string)
}

var myNewFunction = appendFirstArgumentIf(myFunction,
                                          firstArgument=> typeof firstArgument !== 'function')


myNewFunction('New Message', console.log)  // using console.log as callback function
//>>>New Message
myNewFunction(console.log)
//>>>Default Message
```

also possible with this:

```
function mySecondFunction(callback, name, string){
string = string ? string : 'Welcome'
callback(string, name)
}

var myLatestFunction = appendFirstArgumentIf(mySecondFunction,
                                      firstArgument=> typeof firstArgument !== 'function')


myLatestFunction('Hello', console.log, 'John')
//>>>Hello John
myLatestFunction(console.log, 'John')
//>>>Welcome John
```